# Append Python 3D Numpy Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

I have some problem about 3D python numpy

```
import numpy as np
n = 5
m = 4

Sc = np.random.rand(m,n,n)
S1 = np.zeros((1,n+2))
S2 = np.zeros((n,1))

A0 = np.r_[S1, np.c_[S2, Sc[0], S2], S1]
A1 = np.r_[S1, np.c_[S2, Sc[1], S2], S1]
#print(A)
#print(B)
A = np.array([A0,A1])
A.shape
Atmp = np.r_[S1, np.c_[S2, Sc[2], S2], S1]
```

Dimension of `A = (2, 7, 7)`

and dimension of `Atmp = (7,7)`.

How to append `Atmp to A` ?

Comment: `Atmp + A`  doesn't give any errors for me.  Maybe `A += Atmp`?  You need to clarify exactly what you want.

Comment: no, I mean to apend Atmp to array A

Comment: `A = np.array((A0, A1, Atmp))` or `A = np.vstack((A, Atmp[None,...]))`

Comment: `np.append` is another way of using`np.concatenate`, and often a confusing one.  `np.r_` and `np.c_` are also `concatenate` frontends.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't `concatenate`/`append`/`stack` arrays if you can help it, especially big ones.  It's very wasteful of memory and slow.

Assign `A = np.empty((m, n+2, n+2))` and then fill it with `A[i] = np.r_[S1, np.c_[S2, Sc[i], S2], S1]`.  Or do it vectorized and get rid of the `for` loops:

```
A = np.zeros((m, n+2, n+2))
A[:,1:-1,1:-1] = Sc
```

or even do it in one line:

```
A = np.pad(Sc, ((0,0),(1,1),(1,1)), 'constant', constant_values = 0)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It's very helpful for my problem. And this is a big dimension array problem, can you suggest some reading for this method?

Comment: [indexing docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) and [`np.pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html)

Comment: I think this answer not only give me the answer of the problem but also new way to use big problem array in python. Thakn you very much and I vote this for the acceptance answer

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
A = np.concatenate([A, [Atmp]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think, this answer work for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reshape to put the array in the right form:

```
np.reshape(Atmp,(1, Atmp.shape[0], Atmp.shape[1]))
```

and then append as

```
np.vstack([A, np.reshape(Atmp,(1, 7, 7))])
```